# grep with -f option returns different results based on the order of the patterns file

Tags: macos, grep, gnu

I am trying to match keywords listed in one file from text in another file. The keywords file is new line separated.

`grep` returns different results based on the order of the keywords (not the input file).

Here is an example.

With this input

```
# input.txt
TRITONS, sea-deities; they sung the marriage chorus of ACHILLES.
```

Case 1

```
# terms.txt
ACHILLES
TRITONS

# grep returns just one match
grep -o -f terms.txt input.txt  
ACHILLES
```

Case 2: I just changed the order of the keywords file

```
# terms.txt
TRITONS
ACHILLES

# grep returns both matches ! 
grep -o -f terms.txt input.txt 
TRITONS
ACHILLES
```

Trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: You don't use `input.txt` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry my bad. updated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with GNU grep 3.4 - I get two matches with both variants of `terms.txt`

Comment: I'm using the one that ships with a Mac `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. I'll try GNU grep.

Comment: Yes this is not reproducible with with Gnu Grep `ggrep (GNU grep) 3.4`. This version finds both terms no matter what the order is. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you would like to edit your question and tag it with the relative operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue in `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` (this is the default version that ships on Mac High Sierra).

Fixed by using `Gnu Grep ggrep (GNU grep) 3.4.` instead.

Installed via `brew install grep`.

Note that this version of grep is now called `ggrep`.